# Unable to do file upload on RestController behind SpringSecurity (got 404)

Tags: spring, file-upload, spring-security, spring-restcontroller, spring-oauth2

Im trying to do fileupload (via RestController and also had tried with Controller), but it always returns a 404.

There is a reverse proxy in front of this app, hence entry point is /v2/service.

All the other API calls are working fine, except for this file upload. Please advise.

My Configuration

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnClass({ Servlet.class, StandardServletMultipartResolver.class, MultipartConfigElement.class })
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "multipart", name = "enabled", matchIfMissing = true)
@EnableConfigurationProperties(MultipartProperties.class)
public class MultipartAutoConfiguration {

     @Autowired
     private MultipartProperties multipartProperties = new MultipartProperties();

     @Bean(name="multipartResolver")
     public CommonsMultipartResolver getResolver() throws IOException{
        CommonsMultipartResolver resolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
        resolver.setMaxUploadSizePerFile(1242880);
        return resolver;
     }

     @Bean
     @ConditionalOnMissingBean
     public MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement() {
         return this.multipartProperties.createMultipartConfig();
     }

     @Bean(name = DispatcherServlet.MULTIPART_RESOLVER_BEAN_NAME)
     @ConditionalOnMissingBean(MultipartResolver.class)
     public StandardServletMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
         return new StandardServletMultipartResolver();
     }
}
```

And my controller: (i have tried RestController and Controller, both gave me 404)

```
@RestController
public class UploadController {

     @Autowired
     private ImageService imageService;

     @RolesAllowed({ "ROLE_USER" })
     @RequestMapping(value="/api/item/image/u", method=RequestMethod.POST)
     public String handleFileUpload(@RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file) throws ImageSizeException, IOException{
          System.out.println("Upload start : ");
          returns "YEY";
    }
 }
```

A snippet of my spring security config:

```
@Configuration
public class OAuth2ServerConfiguration {

     private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "batmanservice";

     @Configuration
     @EnableResourceServer
     protected static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends
        ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
        // @formatter:off
        resources.resourceId(RESOURCE_ID);
        // @formatter:on
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api").hasRole("USER")
                .antMatchers("/batsearch").anonymous();
                http.csrf().disable();
        // @formatter:on
    }
 }

   @Configuration
   @EnableAuthorizationServer
   protected static class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends
        AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

       private TokenStore tokenStore = new InMemoryTokenStore();

       @Autowired
       @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
       private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

       @Autowired
       private UserService userService;

       @Autowired
       private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

       @Override
       public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
           oauthServer
             .tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
             .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
       }

       @Override
       public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)
            throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
           endpoints
              .tokenStore(this.tokenStore)
              .authenticationManager(this.authenticationManager)
              .userDetailsService(this.userDetailsService);
        // @formatter:on
       }

       @Override
       public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
           // @formatter:off
           clients
               .inMemory()
                  .withClient("batclient")
                    .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "authorization_code", "refresh_token")
                    .authorities("ROLE_USER")
                    .scopes("read", "write", "trust")
                    .accessTokenValiditySeconds(18000)
                    .resourceIds(RESOURCE_ID)
                    .secret("batmansecret");
             // @formatter:on
        }

        @Bean
        @Primary
        public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
             DefaultTokenServices tokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
             tokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
             tokenServices.setTokenStore(this.tokenStore);
             return tokenServices;
       }
   }
}
```

And here is how i tested using postman:
[image]
which is:

```
POST /v2/service/api/item/image/u?access_token=9105dbcd-00a4-4614-aa69-a53e83bc356e HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Authorization: Basic YzNidTRwcDBuZTpGRjAxNURFQUQwNjVBMEEw
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 2ad8977e-842e-c442-e480-9004b9d21854
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW

------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename=""
Content-Type: 


------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""


------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--
```

Answer (score 0):

In your UploadController implementation, @RequestMapping is at path "/api/item/image/u" but the api is called at "/**service**/api/item/image/u". I cannot see "service/" mapped anywhere as prefix or in your controller hence 404.

Comment: thanks @Himanshu. actually i forgot to mention there is a reverse proxy (hence /v2/service) which is in front of this app.